# Cisco top-talker data

Tags: cisco, router, netflow

I have enabled top-talkers ingress/egress

ip flow-top-talkers
 top 10
 sort-by bytes
 cache-timeout 1

I wanted to confirm a couple things with the output below

1.) When I see a (K), I assume its Kilobytes, NOT Kilobits?
2.) I see two different flows for the same source. Could an example of this be when someone is downloading a file and uploading or streaming music simultaneously?

```
R2#show ip flow top-talkers

SrcIf         SrcIPaddress    DstIf         DstIPaddress    Pr SrcP DstP Bytes
Fa0/0         192.168.1.1     Local         192.168.1.2     01 0000 0800  2257K
Fa0/0         192.168.1.1     Local         192.168.1.2     01 0000 0000   165K
2 of 10 top talkers shown. 2 flows processed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you read the heading over the K quantities, it says, "Bytes."
2. A host can have many different simultaneous flows.  Just about everything today multitasks. You can download multiple things and upload multiple things all while using VoIP.